# Bluetooth Input Hub

Tags: sensors, hardware, bluetooth

I am wondering if anyone knows about some existing 'off the shelf" hardware options where some device could connect to this Bluetooth "Input Hub" where this hub can have inputs plugged into it and any data received via that input would inform the connected Bluetooth device that sensor X sent value Y.

This would allow any Bluetooth capable device to receive/read inputs and do something with that information.

Not sure where to ask if this is not the right place. Thanks in advance.
Also does Bluetooth disconnect after some long time of being connected?

(Output is not required but bonus if it can)

Comment: What real world problem are you trying to solve. Building what you describe with any number of Nordic SoC world be easy, but I don't see a use case for something as general as you describe

Comment: What’s your notion of “off the shelf”? Some board you can then add sensors to? Or something completely packaged? Of the former, anything ESP32 based should work, as well as NRF51 or NRF52 based. Adafruit must have a dozen such boards. You can also look at the M5Stack, Pycom’s devices, and probably more. This seems like a very broad question to me...

Comment: Also what kind of "inputs" are you talking about? Analog levels? Digital on/off signals? I2C? SPI? UART? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very very broad, but here are a few starting points...

Nearly any device with BLE support and GPIO inputs could serve that purpose, including all those that are ESP32-based (expect those based on the new ESP32-S2 which doesn't have Bluetooth), NRF51* or NRF52* based devices, and many more.

In terms of development boards:

- Adafruit have at least the Huzzah32 ([breakout](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4172) or [Feather](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3405)), the [Circuit Playground Bluefruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4333), the [Flora Wearable Bluefruit LE](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2487), the [ItsyBitsy nRF52840 Express](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4481), the [Feather nRF52840 Express](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4062)...
- Pycom have many boards, including the [WiPy](https://pycom.io/product/wipy-3-0/), which can be coupled with an expansion board, or the PyScan, PySense or PyTrack which have sensors on board
- The [BBC micro:bit](https://microbit.org)
- Nordic Semiconductor's [nRF52840 dongle](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Kits/nRF52840-Dongle), and variants from [Makerdiary](https://store.makerdiary.com/products/nrf52840-mdk-usb-dongle), [AprBrother](https://blog.aprbrother.com/product/april-usb-dongle-52840), Minew, etc. Those are designed to run off a USB port, but as long as you provide power to them they can run standalone.
- Boards which already have a few sensors: [Adafruit Feather nRF52840 Sense](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4516)
- The dozens of other ESP32-based boards you can find everywhere
- There's of course also the Raspberry Pi, especially the [Raspberry Pi Zero W](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-zero-w/), and a lot of boards from Orange Pi, Banana Pi, Nano Pi, and so on, though this may be overkill (but you get a full Linux system and a lot more powerful processor).

In terms of "packaged" devices (but programmable, and with inputs available, though not quite easily accessible when in their package, but they also have built-in sensors):

- Nordic Semidonductor's [Thingy52](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Prototyping-platforms/Nordic-Thingy-52)
- Espruino's [Puck.js](https://www.puck-js.com)
- Ruuvi's [Ruuvitag](https://ruuvi.com)
- [M5Stack's various core modules](https://m5stack.com/collections/m5-core), which actually have accessible pins and a Groove connector

Really, the choice is yours. Depending on what you want to connect to them, the features you want, how you want to power it, whether you want a prepackaged device or have more freedom, your favorite language (Python, C, Javascript...), and so on, one or the other (and possibly many, many more) could be the best fit.

Comment: Thanks @jcaron! I was after some direction in a broad sense and you have done that perfectly! I will look into these as it seems there are a few approaches that you have listed, so thank you.